# Storing Phoenix static assets on Amazon S3

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, elixir, assets, phoenix-framework

I need to provide some context before asking the question:

**CONTEXT**

I have a **Phoenix** application that is being deployed to **Heroku**. As default, **Brunch** is being used to compile the *Static Assets* like `.js`,`.css` and images.

- Those *assets* are stored on `./assets` (as of **Phoenix 1.3**).
- Those *assets* are compiled to `./priv/static/`.

The compilation process generates a `cache_manifest.json`, after the *assets* are [digested using MD5 fingerprinting](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/mix-tasks#section--mix-phoenix-digest-).

It maybe important to notice I'm using **CloudFlare's** free version as a CDN.

**I'm not concerned about *user uploaded assets*, I'm talking about the app's assets**

*Relevant part of the apps `config/prod.exs`*

````
config :bespoke_work, BespokeWork.Web.Endpoint, 
  on_init: {BespokeWork.Web.Endpoint, :load_from_system_env, []},
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: System.get_env("HEROKU_HOST"), port: System.get_env("HEROKU_PORT")],
  static_url: [scheme: "https", host: System.get_env("STATIC_ASSETS"), port: 443],
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json",
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")```
````

---

**QUESTION**

1. How can I prevent Heroku from building the assets and, instead, during deploy, automatically upload the digested assets to an **Amazon S3** Bucket?
2. Will that make Heroku's slug smaller?

---

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

1. Reducing **Heroku's** Slug Size:

   • On the `Procfile` redirect `mix phx.digest` to output digested items to `/dev/null`.

   or

   • Redefine `mix deps.compile` for *Prod*, not generating the assets.

---

2. Generate the assets locally.

---

3. Either Manually upload them or use a Shell Script to upload them to **S3**. (In my case probably using **Codeship's** <s>Amazing</s> **Amazon S3** deployment)

---

4. Use `static_url` to generate paths "pointing" to the **S3 Bucket**.

---

• **Is there any simpler way to accomplish this?** •

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a good idea... it might even be considered an anti-pattern.

But, if for some reason, that is absolutely necessary, this is one way to do it:

#### Reducing the Slug Size on Heroku:

- [**Heroku** allows the use of a `.slugignore`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) file for basic use cases (like *.pdf* or *.psd*)

  **and / or**
- The [slug cleaner buildpack](https://github.com/stevo550/buildpack-slug-cleaner) cleans any non-required static assets after they've been processed.

---

#### Automating Amazon S3 Uploads

• This should be done through a shell script.